# Trouble adding tooltip to my d3 tree nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add a mouseover tooltip to my nodes in a d3 v4 tree.  I am following this d3 v3 example here: http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/10699411

I that example I see this code:

```
.on('mouseover', function() {
                    var fo = svg.append('foreignObject')
                        .attr({
                            'x': anchor.w - tip.w,
                            'y': anchor.h + tip.h,
                            'width': foWidth,
                            'class': 'svg-tooltip'
                        });
                    var div = fo.append('xhtml:div')
                        .append('div')
                        .attr({
                            'class': 'tooltip'
                        });
   ...
```

I believe I am doing the same in my code:

```
      .on('mouseover', function (d) {
        var foHeight = 100;
        var foWidth = 100;
        var t = 50, k = 15;
        var tip = {'w': (3/4 * t), 'h': k};
        var anchor = {'w': 100/3, 'h': 100/3};

        var fo = svg.append('foreignObject')
          .attr('x', 0)
          .attr('y', 0)
          .attr('width', this.rect_width)
          .attr('height', this.rect_height)
          .attr('class', 'svg-tooltip');

        var div = fo.append('xhtml:div')
           .append('div')
           .attr({'class': 'tooltip'});
   ...
```

but in my code the `div` is `null`.  I am pretty sure that is because of the `.attr({'class': 'tooltip'})` line, but I don't understand why adding the line `.attr({'class': 'tooltip'})` would cause `div` to be `null`.  If I remove the line `.attr({'class': 'tooltip'})`, `div` is not null but my tooltip does not display when I mouseover a node.

I have this in my css file:

```
.d3-chart {
  width: 100%;
  min-height:600px;
}

.wordwrap {
  white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */
  white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera <7 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word; /* IE */
}

.svg-tooltip {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tooltip {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #4A22FF;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference uses d3v3, which allows passing objects to `.attr()` and `.style()` representing multiple (or single in this case) attributes or styles.

```
selection.attr("property","value")
```

Was equivalent to:

```
selection.attr({property:"value"})
```

Since and including d3v4, only the first option is valid.

As seen here in v3:

```js
d3.select("body")
  .append("p")
  .attr("class","underline")
  .text("Underlined");

d3.select("body")
  .append("p")
  .attr({"class":"underline"})
  .text("Underlined too");
  
d3.select("body")
  .append("p")
  .attr({"class":"underline","style":"color:blue"})
  .text("Underlined and blue");
  
// Classes can also be assigned 
d3.select("body")
  .append("p")
  .attr({"class":"underline"})
  .classed("small",true)  // with selection.classed
  .text("Underlined and small");
```

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.small {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Starting with d3v4, `selection.attr()` and `selection.style()` no longer accept objects (*if using d3-multi-selection, .attrs() and .styles() do*)

Seen here:

```js
d3.select("body")
  .append("p")
  .attr("class","underline")
  .text("Underlined");
  
d3.select("body")
  .append("p")
  .classed("underline",true)
  .text("Underlined");  
  
d3.select("body")
  .append("p")
  .attr({"class":"underline"})
  .text("Underlined");
```

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Rather than using an object to assign class, your tooltip can gain the class you want with:

```
div.classed("tooltip",true)
div.attr("class","tooltip") // will remove previously assigned classes
```

If using `selection.attr({property:"value"})` with d3v4, this causes an error and nothing chained to it will fire, so the html of the div will be null - you never execute the code that populates the div.

Comment: Hey thanks Andrew.  I was wondering if you could help me over one more hurdle.  If you could please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55543619/d3-tree-tooltip-does-not-appear I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Will take a look momentarily.